# Rails4 and tabulous?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zurb-foundation

This is the view hello.html.erb using zurb foundation and tabulous:

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <div class="contain-to-grid">
 <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
    <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name">
            <h1><a href="#">Hello World!</a></h1>
        </li>
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a>
 </li>
      </ul>

 <ul class="center">
 <li style="padding-top:55px;">
  <%= form_tag("/salutation/hello", method: "post") do %>
    <div class="large-6 columns" style="padding-left:250px;border:0px;
  margin-right:0px;padding-right:0px;">
        <%= text_field_tag(:find_stuff) %>
     </div>
     <div>
          <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "large-1 small-3 columns",
  style:"color:white;border:none;background-color:red;height:28px;margin:0px;"%>
     </div>

  <% end %>
 <a href="#" style="padding-left:80px;">Login|Register</a>


  </li>
 </ul>    

 </nav>
 <%= tabs %>
 <%= subtabs %>

</div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="six columns">
   <div class="panel" style="min-height:800px">
 <p><%= @test %></p>
 <p><%= @test %></p>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>



 </body>
 </html>
```

This is the controller salutation.rb:

```
class SalutationController < ApplicationController
  def new
   @test = ''
  end

  def hello
   @message = 'Hello, World!'
   @test = params[:find_stuff]  
  end
end
```

This is very simple code for reading the text in the search box, and writing to the view. I have a 
file tabulous.rb, which adds menu tabs to the screen. The code for tabulous.rb is:

```
tabulous.setup do

 tabs do

  news_tab do
   text          { 'News' }
   link_path     { news_index_path }
   visible_when  { true }
   enabled_when  { true }
   active_when   { in_action('any').of_controller('news') }
  end

  homes_tab do
   text          { 'Homes' }
   link_path     { homes_path }
   visible_when  { true }
   enabled_when  { true }
   active_when   { in_action('any').of_controller('homes') }
 end

end

customize do


end


 use_css_scaffolding do
  background_color '#ccc'
  text_color '#444'
  active_tab_color '#fff'
  hover_tab_color '#ddd'
  inactive_tab_color '#aaa'
  inactive_text_color '#888'
 end

 end
```

When I tried these tabs without the zurb foundation styling the form displays the menu tabs
fine, but when I embed this form in the view there is no display, and the form just displays the main top bar with the search box. Why this happens I can't figure out - is 
this because of the styling by zurb foundation, that breaks it, or any other reason?

Answer (score 0):

Why use `tabulous.rb`? Foundation already supports tabs out of the box. You can refer to the documentation for the [markup required to create them](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tabs.html). It'll be easier that way.

As an aside, I would really recommend against adding inline CSS in your markup. There should be a separation of concerns between your markup (for content), and your CSS (for style). Incidentally, this is the same reason that tabulous might not be a great choice for tabs. It's not Ruby's job to create structure and style.

Comment: Sorry for the markup - it really was a bother! But, yes tabulous has subtabs which are easy to manipulate, and stable too. Anyway so to explore options, using foundation as tabs would require - the following modifications, for each panel12, panel13 <a> tags, ie <dd><a href="#panel2-2">Tab 2</a></dd>, what could be the corresponding erb code to fit for the <a> tag, is it a straight fwd link_to?